# How can I enter an Alias and Have all "" in this Field?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I'm using SQL Server.  I'm trying to enter an Alias field, as a placeholder (haven't received this data yet), and I keep getting an error.  Please see the image bellow.

[image]

I'm not sure how to set this up in SQL Server, but in Access it would simply be like this:

[image]

Any idea how I can make this work?

Thanks to all.
Here is the SQL Script:

```
SELECT        dbo.Plan_ID_Mapping.[Level 3 Service], dbo.Plan_ID_Mapping.[PLAN ID], 
                         dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware.Application_Systems_Software_ID_CI_ID AS CI_ID, 
                         dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware.Application_Systems_Software_Name_CI_Name AS CI_Name, 
                         dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware.Description_Product_Name, dbo.Service_Taxonomy.[Critical Y/N], 
                         dbo.Service_Taxonomy.[Criticality Rationale], dbo.qry_BE.BE, dbo.qry_BE.Street, dbo.qry_BE.City, dbo.qry_BE.ST, dbo.qry_BE.Zip, dbo.qry_BE.Country, 
                         dbo.qry_BE.O_L, dbo.qry_BE.ENTITY, dbo.qry_BE.Comp_Code
FROM            dbo.Plan_ID_Mapping INNER JOIN
                         dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware ON 
                         dbo.Plan_ID_Mapping.[PLAN ID] = dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware.Plan_Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.LocationWorkSpaceByPlanWithAllIn ON 
                         dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware.Plan_Id = dbo.LocationWorkSpaceByPlanWithAllIn.Plan_Id INNER JOIN
                         dbo.qry_BE ON dbo.LocationWorkSpaceByPlanWithAllIn.Location_ID = dbo.qry_BE.BE INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Service_Taxonomy ON dbo.Plan_ID_Mapping.[Level 3 Service] = dbo.Service_Taxonomy.[Level 3]
GROUP BY dbo.Plan_ID_Mapping.[Level 3 Service], dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware.Application_Systems_Software_ID_CI_ID, 
                         dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware.Application_Systems_Software_Name_CI_Name, dbo.Plan_ID_Mapping.[PLAN ID], 
                         dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware.Description_Product_Name, dbo.Service_Taxonomy.[Critical Y/N], 
                         dbo.Service_Taxonomy.[Criticality Rationale], dbo.qry_BE.BE, dbo.qry_BE.Street, dbo.qry_BE.City, dbo.qry_BE.ST, dbo.qry_BE.Zip, dbo.qry_BE.Country, 
                         dbo.qry_BE.O_L, dbo.qry_BE.ENTITY, dbo.qry_BE.Comp_Code
```

Comment: We need to see your code. Your grouping is incorrect as it is.

Comment: Thanks for the code. What is PACKAGE_ID in your screen shot above? It's not contained in your SQL Script

Answer (score 1):

**Quick Answer:**
Uncheck the `GROUP BY` for `PACKAGE_ID`

**EXPLANATION**

It looks like `PACKAGE_ID` is the the alias column you are creating. Which, if there is nothing there, you can't group on it. I rewrote your query below using table alias for clarity and commented out what it really would look like. What is happening is since you don't have anything for `PACKAGE_ID` the SQL statement literally would reflect:

`SELECT NULL AS PACKAGE_ID`

Your error lies in trying to group on the`LITERAL` of `NULL`. You can't group on a literal. For example the query below wouldn't work since we are attempting to group on the literal 2007.  In order to make it work, we'd have to remove the 2007 from the grouping.

```
SELECT
  COLUMN1,
  COLUMN2,
  2007
FROM 
  TABLE1
GROUP BY
  COLUMN1,
  COLUMN2,
  2007
```

**YOUR CODE**

```
SELECT
    map.[Level 3 Service],
    map.[PLAN ID], 
    eh.Application_Systems_Software_ID_CI_ID AS CI_ID, 
    eh.Application_Systems_Software_Name_CI_Name AS CI_Name, 
    eh.Description_Product_Name, 
    tax.[Critical Y/N], 
    tax.[Criticality Rationale], 
    qry.BE, 
    qry.Street, 
    qry.City, 
    qry.ST, 
    qry.Zip, 
    qry.Country, 
    qry.O_L, 
    qry.ENTITY, 
    qry.Comp_Code,
    NULL as PACKAGE_ID            --this is your blank alias field you created
FROM
    dbo.Plan_ID_Mapping map
INNER JOIN
    dbo.All_Enteprise_NONProduction_and_Production_Hardware eh ON 
    map.[PLAN ID] = eh.Plan_Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.LocationWorkSpaceByPlanWithAllIn loc ON 
    eh.Plan_Id = loc.Plan_Id 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.qry_BE qry ON 
    loc.Location_ID =qry.BE 
INNER JOIN
    dbo.Service_Taxonomy tax ON 
    map.[Level 3 Service] = tax.[Level 3]
GROUP BY 
    map.[Level 3 Service], 
    eh.Application_Systems_Software_ID_CI_ID, 
    eh.Application_Systems_Software_Name_CI_Name, 
    map.[PLAN ID],
    eh.Description_Product_Name, 
    tax.[Critical Y/N], 
    tax.[Criticality Rationale], 
    qry.BE, 
    qry.Street, 
    qry.City, 
    qry.ST, 
    qry.Zip, 
    qry.Country, 
    qry.O_L, 
    qry.ENTITY, 
    qry.Comp_Code,
    NULL                 --This is your query trying to group on the blank field
```